# When network los in app notify internet observer automatically iOS

Tags: ios

When I enter in my app after some time internet connection disappear, how to detect it without performing any action in swift. Below is my code that is not working any suggest me how to fix it.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.checkForReachability(_:)), name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil);

        var reachability: Reachability
        do {
            reachability = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
            try reachability.startNotifier()

        } catch {
            print("Unable to create Reachability")

        }


func checkForReachability(notification:NSNotification)
    {
        print(notification)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add one more notification `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`

> Posted shortly before an app leaves the background state on its way to
>   becoming the active app.

and connect a method to check connection.

Also you can call this method directly in viewWillAppear function,
since it works every time your view controller shows to user.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  Reachability class

Reachability *reachability =  [Reachability  reachabilityForInternetConnection];

```
    [reachability startNotifier];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkForReachability:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
```

kReachabilityChangedNotification notify every time when internet connection chage

Comment: Not working in swift, please check it when internet connection goes it does not automatically notify.